# csv.writer adding quote to last term as well as extra line even with newline=''

Tags: python, python-3.x

Prefacing this question by stating that my Python 3 code IS using newline = '' (which was an answer to similar questions), but the behavior is persisting.

This code reads in data from a really big comma delimited text file, buffers one day into a list, then writes that list to a csv file.  I'm getting this odd behavior at the ends of the rows:

**Source data**:

"27/56/4382","81:00:00","5464.4","5464.4","5464.4","3\r\n"
"27/56/4382","81:00:00","5464.4","5464.4","5464.4","3\r\n"

**Output looks like this:**

"27/56/4382","81:00:00","5464.4","5464.4","5464.4","3
"
"27/56/4382","81:00:00","5464.4","5464.4","5464.4","3
"

Code:

```
with open(readfilepath,newline='') as f:
for line in f:
        date1 = date2 # set date1 to date2 so don't get kicked out
        purchline= line # grab line
        parsedline = purchline.split(",") # split up line record
        date2 = parsedline[0] # grab date 2
        if (date1 == date2): # if day hasn't flipped, continue to build buffer
            daybuffer.append(parsedline)
        else:  # day has flipped.  write buffer to file, clear buffer, then append this line (don't lose line!)
            # create writefilepath
            writedate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1,"%M/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y%M%d")
            writefilename = "poa" + writedate + "purRaw.txt"
            writefilepath = writedirectorypath + writefilename

            # write daybuffer to csvfile
            with open(writefilepath,'w',newline='') as writecsv:
                purchwriter = csv.writer(writecsv)
                purchwriter.writerows(daybuffer)

            # wipe out daybuffer
            del(daybuffer[:])
            # add last line to daybuffer
            daybuffer.append(parsedline)
            print("The day hath flipped.")
```

Comment: Try `parsedline = purchline.replace('\r\n', '').split(",")`. Why don't you use the csv module to read the input file?

Comment: Because I have to read the file one line at a time (10gb file) and the days are of variable, unknown length (rows).

Comment: The csv reader module doesn't care about that. Each row will be an inner list in a 2D nested list, perfect for then using `writerows` to write it back out. No different than `split(",")` there when you then just append the varying-length list to another list, but it will account for carriage returns for you. The reader is still an iterable.

Comment: In other words, just iterate through the reader object, don't call `readrows()`

Comment: Thank you I will try that.  Why isn't the writer handling this properly though?  It seems all is in order with "\r\n" after the last line term.  I'm puzzled.  I'm new to Python coming over from R so would like to understand for my further Pythonization.

Comment: I can't test atm but `writerows` will naturally add a newline between each of the nested lists and then I assume the newline characters gets interpreted on top of that. Try my `replace` method and see if it fixes it but I think it's a crude work-around

Comment: Roganjosh using csv.reader worked great thank you.